# I have to maxmimize the child page minimized when it double clicked on its parent page. Is this possible to work in webform in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I had a page with gridview when clicking on the hyperlink in the cell it will open a popup window.

When this popup is minimized I was not able to click anything on the parent page so I need when I double click of mouse on parent page I want  this popup to be maximized. And I was not even able to open new tab also when popup is minimized .so new tab also have to be opened when popup is minimized I dont want to use any extra buttons in my design.

Comment: What have you tried? Do you have any code to show?

Comment: It's impossible to read code in the comments. Please edit your question instead.

Comment: i have commented that because it is not working in mycode

Comment: top.window.moveTo(0,0);
if (document.all) {
top.window.resizeTo(screen.availWidth,screen.availHeight);
}
else if (document.layers||document.getElementById) {
if
(top.window.outerHeight<screen.availHeight||top.window.outerWidth<screen.availWidth){
top.window.outerHeight = screen.availHeight;
top.window.outerWidth = screen.availWidth;
}
}